# Manage.py : Unknown command: 'migrate'

Tags: django, sqlite, django-south

I'm using django and I'm facing a little problem. I would like to use the 'migrate' command with manage.py But when I try I get this error message:

```
  Unknown command: 'migrate'
  Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I have south installed (I installed it with pip), but I still can't use this command. I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For more answers see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346033/south-unknown-command-migrate

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to include `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py.

Comment: I've also encountered a funny one. I have named django project the same 'south' and even if I had it included in INSTALLED_APPS it won't include anything because it was just trying to include itself.

Answer (score 25):

**This is likely caused by following the 1.7 (DEV version) tutorial when we all get the last stable version (1.6) installed by pip.**

It would not appear migrate is even a part of 1.7 in general!

Maybe the following command solve your problem: `python manage.py syncdb`

So either follow [1.6 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) or follow the instructions to install the 1.7 dev version of Django.

Comment: Might not have been appropriate for the original proposer, but this was exactly what I was doing wrong when I got this error.

Comment: You two are awesome for the props!