# How do I get South to work on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, pythonanywhere

[Posted on the PA forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/813/#id_post_5768) regarding this issue I'm facing getting South to work on PA but it seems like the helpful folk on there are busy these days, so here I am.

1. I understand that Django in PA ships with South.
2. In the python shell on a bash console on PA, `import south` does not return any errors.
3. I have included `'south',` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of my settings.py file.
4. I have run `python manage.py syncdb` prior to executing any South commands, and the syncdb runs but I cannot discern any differences in that output from an un-Southed `syncdb`. This is the output:

   > Creating tables ...
   >
   > Installing custom SQL ...
   >
   > Installing indexes ...
   >
   > No fixtures found.
5. Trying to run any South command returns `Unknown Command: 'south_command'`. This applies to all of:

   > python manage.py convert_to_south app_name
   >
   > python manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial
   >
   > python manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto

If it helps, I had set up my web app using the Manual Configuration method as suggested on the [PA tutorial](http://tutorial.pythonanywhere.com/django#edit-the-wsgi-file), rather than as a Django project.

I am literally stuck at step zero, any help at all would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: try doing `import south` in django shell. You might not be using the same python

Comment: Yes, the shell I invoked was through python manage.py shell, on PA, so I think that would have meant that the import south used was legit?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

I wonder if you have an extra 'south' directory -- see the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346033/south-unknown-command-migrate

Comment: Regarding point 4., do you have any south related table in your database?

Comment: You still looking for an answer? it's been open for 3 months now. I dont think you would have waited 3 months for the answer, unless you're patient.

Comment: `import south; print south.__file___`. Incorrect path?

Comment: @Joe, just got back do Django stuff, maybe I'll try again... Pretty much can't do without South.

Comment: Seems like that was a one-off weird thing. South works fine on PA now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you did everything right.

A simple restart of the server (on the Web page of your dashboard) might solve it?

Comment: south works well for me now, I have no what was it I ran into back then. thanks for trying to help. now how do I close this question...

Comment: mark this answer as the correct answer, and the question is closed